# Copy jar file irrespective of any "line separator" it may have

Tags: java, unix, jar

I am writing a program which involves copying a Jar file from one location to another. I am using
 `Files.copy(Path source, Path dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)`
 to copy jar file. If I am writing this code in any other standalone java application, it works just fine.

But in my current project, I am having to set system property as below:

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n")
```

..since I want the other things into Unix.

The jar file I'm trying to copy has **Mixed** lines i.e. (some lines have CR while others have LF)[this I observed using WinMerge tool while comparing both jar files].

So the problem is after setting the above system property, the copied jar file has only UNIX lines because of setting line separator to \n.

So how do I ensure that the copied file is the exact same(i.e it should have Mixed lines and not just Unix)?

The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
    try {
        Files.copy(source, dest.resolve(source.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: This is the screenshot of the jar files comparison. One on the left side is the original jar file & on the right one is the jar file which gets created after copying the original. We can see below each jar file on the right about its carriage return. First one says 'Mixed', second one says 'Unix'. Below that there are two lines that actually show the difference in the jar files]

This is the screenshot of the jar files comparison. One on the left side is the original jar file & on the right one is the jar file which gets created after copying the original. We can see below each jar file on the right about its carriage return. First one says 'Mixed', second one says 'Unix'. Below that there are two lines that actually show the difference in the jar files.

Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: JAR files can contain anything. Not just lines. You should be copying bitwise, not linewise. Hard to believe that `Files.copy()` is causing this problem, if it exists.

Comment: `Files.copy()` copies bytes, not lines.  And `line.separator` isn't for you to set, it is for you to get. I have no belief that the code you've posted is causing whatever problem you have, if any.

Comment: A jar file itself does not have or knows line breaks, a jar file is not a text file, it is an binary file which may contain a collection of files and directories, a jar file is binary file and therefore not affected by `System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n")`

Comment: @A4L You are right. Jar file should not be affected by System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n"). And it does NOT when I try this code in another java application. But in my current project which is a plugin actually, it DOES get affected; and I know that setProperty line is the reason which affects this because I tried giving different arguments for line separator in the setProperty method and the copied jar file gets changed accordingly. For eg, If I give System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n"); then my generated jar file shows that its carriage return is of Windows'.

Comment: Where could I be possibly wrong? :(

Comment: What evidence can you provide that this problem even exists?

Comment: @EJP I'll edit my question by putting a screenshot of the jar files comparison

Comment: I see no differences that have anything to do with line terminators, which for the record are `0x0C` and `0x0A`. I see the occasional `?`, which has quite another explanation, and nothing to do with this code.

Comment: @EJP Oh. Can you tell me how to get rid of these extra "?". I basically want these files to be exactly same.

Comment: They *were* exactly the, after the code you posted. There must have been another process you haven't disclosed.

Comment: @EJP Well, I forgot to mention that when I click OK after selecting the jar files for comparison in WinMerge. A dialog box opens up which says "These files use different carriage return types.". And if it does not have anything to do with line separator then why does the file change accordingly(for eg, from Unix to Windows after I change to System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n"))  when I update the setproperty of line separator? I don't update anything else.

Comment: I don't know anything about WinMerge, but if it thinks that binary files have 'different carriage return types',  it (a) isn't even using correct terminology  (assuming you've reported that correctly), as there is only one carriage return type, and (b) doesn't know what it's talking about. If it has some binary-mode setting you should use it. Otherwise find something else. Why you're even using it remains a mystery. What is the underlying problem, *if any,* that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you by any chance running the command `gradle wrapper` in your project after copying the project or is the task gradle task `wrapper` ran by an other task in your gradle build? Assuming you are using windows and your sources come from linux then If you do so then gradle (which will in your case run in windows) will generate widows style line terminators, and this is nothing you can control from your program.

Comment: @A4L No actually, I'm not running any command, neither is the task "wrapper" run by any other task. All I'm doing is copying the files from one location to other. But thanks for the info